# Find Element based on Element value and Attribute value using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to know if it possible to find elements based on the value of the element and the value of an attribute. I think that I have it working with just one, but can't quite understand how to combine the criteria, or if that is possible.

```
<Fields>
    <Field IsMandatory="true" Type="field">name</Field>
    <Field IsMandatory="true" Type="category">Sub Area</Field>
    <Field IsMandatory="true" Type="category">Country</Field>
</Fields>
```

I would like to select nodes that have the **Type=category** and a value of **Country**

I seem to be able to use these, but don't know how to combine them:

```
SelectNodes("//*[Field='Country']")
```

```
SelectNodes("//*/Fields/Field[@Type='category']")
```

Comment: Try `//Field[@Type="category" and text()="Country"]`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match all the Field elements and specify between square brackets that the `@Type=` attribute is *category* and the `text()` value of the element is *Country*

```
//Field[@Type="category" and text()="Country"]
```